# Matrix left division in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, division

I need to code left matrix division in C++ by using matrices defined in OpenCV. I have made research and found that left matrix division is possible to be done by using cv::solve function. After implementation of a code all element of a result matrix are equal zero, what shouldn't happen because I have checked the same left-division in a Matlab and the result was different.

My code:

```
cv::Mat m1 = cv::Mat(3,3, CV_32F);
cv::Mat m2 = cv::Mat(3,3, CV_32F);
// ... part of code with initialization of the matrices 
cv::Mat result;
cv::solve(m1,m2,result);
```

Is something wrong that I do with function cv::solve? is there other solution for my problem?

Comment: Without knowing what is in the matrices, it's pretty much impossible to figure out what is going on.  Can you give a complete, reproducible example?